# Why I get $e^0=-\inf$ !?

Tags: limits, infinity

I am trying to understand why my calculation for result of $$e^{0}=1$$ is not the same of others like posted [here](https://medium.com/i-math/the-zero-power-rule-explained-449b4bd6934d);

[image]

My calculation is based of using the $\ln$ and **power actions** which is shown below:
$$$$

$$\text{If}\, e^{0}=y\overset{\ln}{\rightarrow} \ln(e^{0})=\ln(y)$$

$${\rightarrow} 0\times \ln(e)=\ln(y)\overset{}{\rightarrow} 0\times 1=\ln(y) \rightarrow 0=\ln(y)\rightarrow y =- \infty !$$

I guess my calculation s not correct by If seems correct, i guess it shows some strange aspect of **e** and **power** (**^**) by the blow

[image]

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: I thought that the only value for $y$ such that $\ln(y)=0$ is $y=1$...

Comment: You may be confusing  $\ln(1)=0$ with $\ln(0)=-\infty$ (in a handwaving sense).  You need the first of these here

Comment: Did you mean $e^{- \infty}\longrightarrow 0$

Comment: Please don't post links to image and videos that are not essential to your question. They just waste time for people reading your question.

Answer (score 5):

You obviously confused logarithm and exponential functions. $\log(y)=0$ means $y=1$.

Answer (score 0):

From your calculations

$\ln y=0 \Longrightarrow y=e^0=1$. This is a circular trivial manipulations. Because, you get $y=e^0$ again. I could not see why $y=- \infty?$.

Here, $y=e^0$ by using only the definition of logarithm. Just definition. Also, $e^0=1$ is based on exponential definition.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a fundamental error.  The logarithm of 0 is negative infinity, the logarithm of 1 is 0.  From ln(y)= 0 you should conclude that y= 1, not negative infinity.